# Connect two modal picker in react native

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-native

I use react native modal picker to drop down the data [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-pickerhttp://)

I used two modal picker, that depend on each other. first one is select service. second one is select city. I want to display cities that have particular services. code is here

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
 Alert,
 TouchableHighlight,
 Image,
 TextInput,
} from 'react-native';

var fullservice=[];
var citylist=[];

import ModalPicker from 'react-native-modal-picker'

class jsonSugei extends Component {


  constructor() {
       super();

       this.state = {

           textInputValue: '',

           dropdownservices:[],

            city:'',
            dropdowncities:[],
             service:'',




       }
   }

   componentDidMount() {

   this.fetchData1();
   this.fetchData2();



 }

 fetchData1(){



   fetch("URL",
   {method: "POST",
   headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
     body: JSON.stringify( {"cacheRequest":["ALL_COMPANY","ALL_SERVICE","HOT_COMPANY","BANNER","PARTNER","CITY","CALANDAR","COMMENTS "]}),
     })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {

       this.setState({
         dropdownservices: responseData.services,
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => { console.warn(error); })
 .done();




 }

 fetchData2(){

   this.state = {
      service:'',

   }


   fetch("URL",
   {method: "POST",
   headers: {
             'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
     body: JSON.stringify( {
   "companyId":"",
   "service":this.state.service,
   "key":""

}),
     })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {

       this.setState({
         dropdowncities: responseData.cities,
       });
     })
     .catch((error) => { console.warn(error); })
 .done();


 }









   render() {


     citylist= this.state.dropdowncities.map(function(item) {

    return {
      key:item.id,
      label: item.name,

    };
    });


    fullservice =this.state.dropdownservices.map(function(item) {

    return {
      key:item.id,
      label: item.name,
    };
    });





       return (
           <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'space-around', padding:50, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}>

               <ModalPicker1
                   data={fullservice}
                   initValue="Select Services!"
                    onChange={(option)=>{this.setState({service:option.label})}}
                    />



                    <ModalPicker
                      style={{marginTop:10}}
                      data={citylist}
                      initValue="City"
                       onChange={(option)=>{ this.setState({city:option.label})}}
                       />


           </View>
       );
   }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
     flex: 1,
     alignItems: 'center',
     justifyContent: 'center',
     backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
   },
   button: {
     borderRadius: 4,
     padding: 10,
     marginLeft: 10,
     marginRight: 10,
     backgroundColor: "#B8C",
   },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('jsonSugei', () => jsonSugei);
```

but not change cities according to the services??? I need help............

Comment: Appreciate if you could re-indent the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The onChange event handler for services ModalPicker should set the state for the cities ModalPicker. Also, the initial fetch for the cities ModalPicker should only fetch cities corresponding to the default service.

Comment: "The onChange event handler for services ModalPicker should set the state for the cities ModalPicker" please explain............

Answer (score 0):

Add another function to first modal picker, and set the data entity as a get state variable,

```
<ModalPicker1 data={fullservice} initValue="Select Services!" onChange={(option)=>{this.setState({service:option.label}),this.secondFunction()}} />
```

Then set the state.cities variable in the second function and use it as the data entity in second modal picker,

```
secondFunction(){
  this.setState({cities:array});
}

<ModalPicker2 data={this.state.cities} initValue="City" onChange={(option)=>{this.setState({city:option.label})}} />
```